# How to access string() type in vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I am connecting to an ole automation server that I wrote which has an "array of strings" property of type "string()" (as reported by the vbscript TypeName command). I want to test that it works in vbscript.

How to I access the individual elements? Accessing them as an array fails.

```
set P=createobject("DIFW.FilterWheel")
If Err Then HandleError()

P.Connected = true
If Err Then HandleError()

WScript.Echo TypeName(P.Names)

For each item in P.Names
    WScript.Echo item
Next

P.Connected = false

p=nil
```

'For each' fails at runtime too on the WScript.echo line with a type mismatch.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `Mid()` and `MidB()` functions.

Comment: No, in both cases, it reports "Type mismatch". Referencing a single string in the array as P.Names(X) reports "Object is not a collection".

Comment: Try to create `ADODB.Stream`, set binary mode, and write the contents to the stream. What will be result of `VarType(P.Names)`?